# How to redirect to default browser from captive portal (cna browser)

Tags: javascript, php, portal, captiveportal

So, i have to redirect user from captive portal to browser, cause captive portal doesnt support japascript and cookies correctly. How anyone an idea?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android: 
just use a tag with href=**intent://yourUrl.com#Intent;scheme=http;end**

Ios:
After opening captive portal just open access to

- gsp1.apple.com
  *.akamaitechnologies.com www.apple.com apple.com www.appleiphonecell.com
  *.apple.com www.itools.info www.ibook.info www.airport.us www.thinkdifferent.us
  *.apple.com.edgekey.net
  *.akamaiedge.net
  *.akamaitechnologies.com

This url's have to return this answer:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <TITLE>Success</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
 Success
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Important: you have to give access to this url's after opening captive portal. So after giving answer to this urls, any link will go to safari or default browser.

Comment: In Android, I tried the similar way mentioned with <a href=intent://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.audionowdigital.player.bbcworld#Intent;scheme=http;end> tag in captive page to open an external link, but it didn't work :-(

Comment: the Android solution works only on Android 11. Has anyone found a solution for <=10?